# OnBeforeUnload behavior is different on second page in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, onbeforeunload

I'm testing `onbeforeunload` behavior using the code snippet from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15240325/188331).

```
var OnBeforeUnload = (function(){
    var
    FDUM = new Function,
    AFFIRM = function(){ return true; };

    var _reg = function(msg,opts){
        opts = opts || {};
        var
            pid = null,
            pre = typeof opts.prefire == 'function' ? opts.prefire : FDUM,
            callback = typeof opts.callback == 'function' ? opts.callback : FDUM,
            condition = typeof opts.condition == 'function' ? opts.condition : AFFIRM;

        window.onbeforeunload = function(){
            return condition() ? (pre(),setTimeout(function(){ pid = setTimeout(callback,20); },1),msg) : void 0; 
        }

        window.onunload = function(){ clearTimeout(pid); };

    }

    var _unreg = function(){ window.onbeforeunload = null;  }

    return {
        register : _reg,
        unregister : _unreg
    };

})();
```

Codes are almost the same. If you look into Developer Console, the output is as follow (make sure you tick the "Preserve log" in Chrome):

**in page 1 (did not click "Next Page" hyperlink)**

- click "Next Page" hyperlink, console log should display "Navigate to ..."
- click "Previous page" in browser toolbar > choose "Stay on this page" > console log displays "Why you exit?" , "Glad you stayed"
- click "Previous page" in browser toolbar > choose "Leave this page" > console log displays "Why you exit?" , "Navigate to..."
- click "Refresh" in browser toolbar > choose "Don't Reload" > console log displays  "Why you exit?" , "Glad you stayed"
- click "Refresh" in browser toolbar > choose "Reload this Page" > console log displays "Why you exit?" , "Navigate to..."

**in page 2 (after clicked "Next Page" hyperlink)**

- click "Next Page" hyperlink, console log should display "Navigate to ..."
- click "Previous page" in browser toolbar > choose "Stay on this page" > console log displays "Why you exit?" , "Glad you stayed"
- click "Previous page" in browser toolbar > choose "Leave this page" > console log displays "Why you exit?", **"Glad you stayed"** , "Navigate to..."
- click "Refresh" in browser toolbar > choose "Don't Reload" > console log displays  "Why you exit?" , "Glad you stayed"
- click "Refresh" in browser toolbar > choose "Reload this Page" > console log displays "Why you exit?", **"Glad you stayed"** , "Navigate to..."

You may notice that the message "Glad you stayed" appears in every option on Page 2. My question is: Why do the behavior changed on page 2? and how to make the behavior consistent in both pages in Chrome?

The above results are tested in Google Chrome v47. Behaviors in both pages are identical in Firefox.

---

Last, the test page is available [here](http://goodsight.hk/raptor/test.html) (can't use JSFiddle as it cannot reproduce the `onbeforeunload` effect)

Comment: read the specs...only thing you can return is a string that for some browsers will be used as message , other browsers won't even honor that message and only use their default

Comment: Noted for the displaying message, but this does not relate to the "Glad you stayed" output in console. It's not the return message of `onbeforeunload`

Comment: can't repro on localhost...

Comment: If you use my test page, the jQuery won't work on localhost.

Comment: @Raptor, localhost, not local file... If jquery didn't worked, I wouldn't have anything else than a `Reference error : $ is undefined`. Here I just have the required behavior. I don't know why it acts like so on your server though.

Comment: JavaScript is on client-side, shouldn't relate to server settings. My server is a standard Apache 2.2 web server on Ubuntu 12.04.