# Detect if user did NOT cancel on a Javascript onbeforeunload Dialog?

Tags: javascript

There's lots of questions on how to raise a dialog before a user leaves, and how to detect if the user decided not to leave.

[javascript before leaving the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080269/javascript-before-leaving-the-page)

[Detecting whether user stayed after prompting onBeforeUnload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821481/detecting-whether-user-stayed-after-prompting-onbeforeunload)

What if I want to do an action only if the user *confirms* that he wants to leave.

But I don't want to run action() if the user cancels the leave dialog and ends up staying on the page.

**How can I detect confirm for `onbeforeunload` JavaScript Dialog?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `unload` event. This event will be fired after they confirm the dialogue displayed because of the onbeforeunload event.

```
window.addEventListener("unload", function() {
    console.log("Bye!");
});
```

Note that there are restrictions on what you can do in `beforeunload` and `unload` event handlers, to prevent malware that completely prevents you from closing the window/tab.